# How to start a program on user login

Tags: linux, bash, debian, kde, login-screen

On Debian Lenny with KDE.

I added a command to the bottom of $HOME/.profile to open transmission so my complete .profile looks like this: (everything except the last line is default)

```
...
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

transmission-gtk
```

What happens though is when I log in transmission pops up and the desktop won't load until I close it.

I thought the purpose of $HOME/.profile was to run scripts/programs when a user logs in. Am I misunderstanding its purpose?

Comment: Run it in the background? `transmission-gtk &`. Then the script can finish and continue with your login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put an `&` after transmission-gtk, which should force it to run in the background. It would be `transmission-gtk &`.